# Is there any option to avoid creating more endpoints in AWS API gateway for lambda function

Tags: python, api, aws-lambda

Without creating many API gateway for a lambda functions but creating a sub endpoints for the same lambda,

Something like.. https://api_url/test_api and after that https://api_url/test_api2, https://api_url/test_api3 and so on.,

Please let me if there is any alternate option available like my expectation mentioned above or any other suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a lambda function from the console, rather use a serverless framework. One such framework is [Chalice](https://github.com/aws/chalice) for Python Lambda functions. Alternatively you can use [Serverless](https://serverless.com/) which supports Javascript.

**Chalice** is a microframework for writing serverless apps in python. It allows you to quickly create and deploy applications that use AWS Lambda.

Chalice can use one API Gateway entry point that can fan off into multiple lambda functions or you can create multiple api gateway routes similar to your example which can call the same python function with different parameters or different functions.

The great thing about frameworks such as Chalice is that the entire deployment, supporting libraries, cloudformation process etc is all done with code and saved to your git repo.

Here are two medium posts on using Chalice [here](https://medium.com/@sanjoybasu/building-python-serverless-applications-on-aws-lambda-with-aws-chalice-8dbf2dc07b63) and [here](https://hackernoon.com/aws-lambda-651cb3e17b1c).

The documentation found [here](https://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), describes how to use Chalice.

```
pip install chalice
$ chalice new-project helloworld && cd helloworld
$ cat app.py

from chalice import Chalice

app = Chalice(app_name="helloworld")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return {"hello": "world"}

$ chalice deploy
...
https://endpoint/dev

$ curl https://endpoint/api
{"hello": "world"}
```

Once you are up and running you can add additional routes following the examples in the documentation found [here](https://chalice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#tutorial-additional-routing).

If you want some more reading checkout this detailed [post](https://realpython.com/aws-chalice-serverless-python/).

In addition to Chalice, I would recommend creating your project using [CodeStar](https://aws.amazon.com/codestar/). Select from the many templates such as Python Webservice. CodeStar will create a git repository, build pipelines, and deployment scripts which you can edit. This will allow you to create reusable code that is easy to deploy and transfer between environments such as Development, Testing and Production.

Comment: Thank you, Jason, this is an awesome one and I have heard about this. Will mark your answer as done for that pls give me some time thanks again

Comment: @DineshSakthivel No worries, and all the best with your project!

Comment: Now, I realized that StackOverflow will connect the beginner's query directly to the experts...